# Bash, evaluate textual value and remove it's first part in one line

Tags: bash

I need to get git branch name based on commit hash, and remove a prefix of that branch name. I can do it like this

```
branch_name=$(git name-rev --name-only $commit_hash)
branch_name=${branch_name#remotes/origin}
```

But, is there a way to write these into one line?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Not a practical need, but rather style. I want to figure out if there are more pretty ways to write this :)

Comment: Stylistically, it is much "prettier" to keep it in two lines.  The quest for brevity leads to perl.  (Disclaimer: I love perl.  But I also like being able to read code.)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. Unless there are some brilliant options to do it in one line and still readable :)

Comment: Doing it in one line likely requires spawning another process. An extra `sed` for this small string won't matter unless you're doing it in a loop on a large dataset, which seems pretty unlikely for branches... but separate statements are easier to individually add **comments** on, which people do not do enough of (imnsho).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are opting for forking sub-shells and command pipes, rather than running two commands in the same thread on separate lines; you can at least maintain using shell's built-in commands, rather than spawning `sed` or `awk`.

```sh
branch_name="$(set -- "$(git name-rev --name-only "$commit_hash")"; echo "${1#remotes/origin }")"
```

Finally to avoid re-assigning `branch_name` a new value, and making it a mutable variable with an invalid intermediate value (witch is a questionable coding practice); you can split the above into two commands/lines:

```sh
set -- "$(git name-rev --name-only "$commit_hash")"
branch_name="${1#remotes/origin }"
```

- This way there is only one fork for the `git` command.
- The output from the `git` command is stored as argument 1.
- `branch_name` is only assigned once its final value from parsing argument 1.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
branch_name=$(git name-rev --name-only $commit_hash | sed 's@remotes/origin@@')
```

or

```
branch_name=$(git name-rev --name-only $commit_hash | awk -F'remotes/origin *' '{print $2}')
```

Comment: @yekope Note that this runs another external command instead of removing the substring in the current shell. Whether you need this overhead to reduce the number of lines is your decision, though.

Comment: Yup, I don't see it more readable or compact, and as you've said, it has some overhead. But indeed, this is the correct answer to my question (I'll mark it a bit later, just wondering if there are more ways to do it :))